# how to pass cookie from the browser to the API

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlets, cookies

I am developing single sign on project. for that,

My api running on one server (ex : 1.1.1.1)

My UI running on another server (ex : 1.1.1.2)

here I need to enable the remember me option in the UI side, for that after successful logon in the API, I am redirecting to the UI server(1.1.1.2) with the cookie, If I check the response , the Set-Cookie header is present. But it is not creating any cookie. so I cannot login automatically on the next login click. please suggest some ways to achieve the single sign on.

I am using

1. Java servlet with resteasy for API
2. Angular js for UI

Comment: you'll need enable 3rd party cookies at the very least. cookies and IP addresses suck together

Comment: @JaromandaX, please give some links for that.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265 will tell you what you need to know about domain matching and thrid party cookies etc

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you.